# how to pass two values or arguments from two dropdown to ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showUser(str,str1) {
                if (str=="") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                    return;
                }
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str+"&s="+str1,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <option value="0">Select a person:</option>
                <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
                <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
                <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
                <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
            </select>
            <select name="users2" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
                <option value="0">Select a person:</option>
                <option value="5">Peter Griffin</option>
                <option value="6">Lois Griffin</option>
                <option value="7">Joseph Swanson</option>
                <option value="8">Glenn Quagmire</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div id="txtHint">
            <b>
                Person info will be listed here.
            </b>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

From this HTML page i want to pass two values to one ajax function but it can't pass value from second dropdown. But from first dropdown which is with name 'users' pass value fine to ajax but from 2nd dropdown it cant pass value to ajax function

Below check getdata.php
**getdata.php**

```
<?php
echo "ab";  
echo $_GET['s'];
if($_GET['q']==1)
{
    echo "7";
}
if($_GET['q']==2)
{
    echo "2";
}
if($_GET['q']==3)
{
    echo "3";
}
if($_GET['s']==7)
{
    echo "4";
}
?>
```

Comment: hi Roland where i add this in my code? can uh please tell me?

Comment: it is because your `onchange` event only get the value of the element where you put the function. What you need to do is to remove the parameters on your function and call the value of two select tags inside your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is because You are always looking for the first selectbox value not the selectbox.Change your function to this:

```
function showUser() {

    var str=document.getElementById("user").value;
    var str1=document.getElementById("user2").value;
  if (str==0) {// if nothing is selected from first drop down
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  .......
........//rest of the code
}
```

and your select to this:

```
<select name="users" id="user" onchange="showUser()"><!--added id here in select-->

<select name="users2" id="user2" onchange="showUser()"><!--added id here in select-->
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the form data from inside the onChange handler function.

```
<form id="thisform" onChange="showUser()">
<select name="users">
    <option value="0">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
    <option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
    <option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
    <option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
</select>
<select name="users2">
    <option value="0">Select a person:</option>
    <option value="5">Peter Griffin</option>
    <option value="6">Lois Griffin</option>
    <option value="7">Joseph Swanson</option>
    <option value="8">Glenn Quagmire</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Function Handler could look similiar to this:

```
function showUser(){
    var formElements = document.getElementById("thisform");
    var usersValue = formElements[0].value);
    var users2Value = formElements[1].value);

    // do stuff  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Here you call javascript function with 2 parameter & these both parameters requires...so go with below code...
```

//In your code when 1st parameter set the 2nd is empty... & when send onchange call then 1st will empty

```
<html>
<head>

<script>
function showUser() {

    var str;
    var str1;

    str=document.getElementById("users").value;
    str1=document.getElementById("users2").value;
    alert(str);
    alert(str1);
    if(str!=''&& str!=0 && str1!='' && str1!=0)
    { 
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
      if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) 
     {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
     }
     }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","getdata.php?q="+str+"&s="+str1,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
    }
}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" id="users" onchange="showUser()">
<option value="0">Select a person:</option>
<option value="1">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="2">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="3">Joseph Swanson</option>
<option value="4">Glenn Quagmire</option>
</select>
<select name="users2" id="users2" onchange="showUser()">
<option value="0">Select a person:</option>
<option value="5">Peter Griffin</option>
<option value="6">Lois Griffin</option>
<option value="7">Joseph Swanson</option>
<option value="8">Glenn Quagmire</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>

<?php
echo "ab";  
echo $_GET['s'];
    if($_GET['q']==1)
    {
        echo "7";
    }
    if($_GET['q']==2)
    {
        echo "2";
    }
    if($_GET['q']==3)
    {
        echo "3";
    }
    if($_GET['s']==7)
    {
        echo "4";
    }
?>
```